# .NET MAUI Preview 5 WinUI - nothing is displayed, blank (indigo) screen

Tags: .net, blazor, winui-3, maui

Running the sample app or a new app from the template renders only a blank indigo screen. App loads and runs, yet none of the web content renders and no error is given.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need the latest Edge WebView2 runtime installed and the app should render. https://aka.ms/winui3/webview2download/